# HTTP Strict Transport Security not respected for IP addresses

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

I set up a cert for an IP address with nginx, and enabled http strict transport security:

```
add_header  Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
```

The directive is in the header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 17 Sep 2014 22:46:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
```

... but it's not respected by the browsers (instead they do for FQDN).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you direct you browser to IP address (`https://xx.xx.xx.xx/`) instead of domain name and expect it to obey HSTS rule?

But [RFC 6797 Appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#appendix-A) explicitly exclude IP addresses:

> HSTS Hosts are identified **only via domain names** -- explicit IP address identification of all forms is excluded.

Comment: I hope so! I would hate to get assigned a dynamic IP that had a pinned public key! Or even pinned https if that's what I didn't want.