# HSTS doesn't work on browser when dealing with a self-signed certificate

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate, self-signed, hsts

We have a web portal and I need to add HSTS header in the response. 
Ours is an on-premise solution, so we use a self-signed certificate. I have added the hsts header in the response & I need to check whether it really works.

I understand that for HSTS to work, there shouldn't be any certificate issues & first we need to access https://somesite.com  then in the next pass http request will be automatically redirected to https at client side itself.

So, I installed our self-signed certificate in the chrome browser & restarted the browser. Now my connection to our web application was secure. But HSTS doesn't seem to work. In the successive calls to http://somesite.com, still we redirect (302) to https (automatic client side redirection to https doesn't happen). One thing to note here is, there is no domain name associated with our web application, we access it with our server's ip within our comapany's LAN.

Any idea how to get HSTS working?

Comment: So if the self-signed certificate issued to an IP address? Is there a green padlock or a red padlock after visiting the site over HTTPS in the browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Strict Transport Security not respected for IP addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901602/http-strict-transport-security-not-respected-for-ip-addresses)